# Цикл for для объектов. Как ограничить кол-во отображаемых

Tags: python, django

Есть модель БД. Нужно вывести на страничку ТОП продаваемых товаров. Отсеиваю по кол-ву продаж. Вопрос как ограничить результат , например 3мя товарами(в наличии порядка 20)?
вью:

```
def main_page(request):
    ...
    top_tovars = Tovars.objects.order_by('tovar_pokypok')
    render_to_response('main.html', {..., 'top_tovars': top_tovars}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

html:

```
...
{% for top_tovar in top_tovars %}
<li><a href='/tovar/some/{{ tovar.id }}/'><img src='{{ top_tovar.tovar_img.url }}'></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему бы не передать top_tovars[:3]?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/62914)

Comment: @Streletz является.

Comment: Впрочем, дописать в ответ, кого где это передать и что это вообще такое, всё равно не помешает

Answer (score 1):

Или например так:

```
{% for top_tovar in top_tovars|slice:":3" %}
```

[Документация на slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)